# Modify a particular row/column of a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do I modify particular a row or column of a NumPy array?

For example I have a NumPy array as follows:

```
P = array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6]])
```

How do I change the elements of first row, `[1, 2, 3]`, to `[7, 8, 9]` so that the `P` will become:

```
P = array([[7, 8, 9],
           [4, 5, 6]])
```

Similarly, how do I change second column values, `[2, 5]`, to `[7, 8]`?

```
P = array([[1, 7, 3],
           [4, 8, 6]])
```

Answer (score 68):

Rows and columns of NumPy arrays can be selected or modified using the square-bracket indexing notation in Python.

To select a *row* in a 2D array, use `P[i]`. For example, `P[0]` will return the first row of `P`.

To select a *column*, use `P[:, i]`. The `:` essentially means "select all rows". For example, `P[:, 1]` will select all rows from the second column of `P`.

If you want to change the values of a row or column of an array, you can assign it to a new list (or array) of values of the same length.

To change the values in the first *row*, write:

```
>>> P[0] = [7, 8, 9]
>>> P
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

To change the values in the second *column*, write:

```
>>> P[:, 1] = [7, 8]
>>> P
array([[1, 7, 3],
       [4, 8, 6]])
```

Comment: You said above: "If you want to change the values of a row or column of an array, you can assign it to a new list (or array) of values of the same length." But is it OK to just alter the source array without copying it? I have an array, a, and then I just do a[: ,1] = [1, 2, 3] and that alters my source array. Are there any issues in just altering the source in place without copying, etc.or is that OK practice?

Comment: @mbird: it's fine to modify an array without copying it, as long as you are happy for any other array that shares the same underlying data as `a` to potentially be modified too. For example if you set `b = a[0]` and then set `a[: ,1] = [1, 2, 3]`, the change of values would also affect `b`. (Often this is the desired outcome, but not always.)

Answer (score 6):

In a similar way if you want to select only two last columns for example but all rows you can use:

```
print P[:,1:3]
```

Comment: This should be a comment to the above answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have lots of elements in a column:

```
import numpy as np
np_mat = np.array([[1, 2, 2],
                   [3, 4, 5],
                   [5, 6, 5]])
np_mat[:,2] = np_mat[:,2] * 3
print(np_mat)
```

It is making a multiplied by 3 change in third column:

```
    [[ 1  2  6]
     [ 3  4 15]
     [ 5  6 15]]
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the OP's question, regarding changing specific rows/columns of the array.

Comment: what do you mean it's obviously special column! and it's a solution for bigger matrix that you can't add one by one.

Comment: that helped to know how to update all values of a particular column.