# Is there a function for changing all row values in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, replace

I have got a 5 by 5 numpy array and a list of 3 values

```
a = np.array[([[0,4,5,8,2],
 [2,3,4,1,3],
 [2,3,4,1,3],
 [2,3,4,1,3],
 [2,3,4,1,3]])

BC = np.array([0,3,4])
```

with this condition, every row and column of the BC must be 0. In this case, the first, fourth and fifth row and column. The output therefore needs to be

```
[0,0,0,0,0
0,3,4,0,0
0,3,4,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0]
```

Of course it is possible to do a[0,0] = 0 and then for every place in the matrix, but I want to use a for loop because the original matrix is 12*12. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify a particular row/column of a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975769/modify-a-particular-row-column-of-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to slice the array then assign it to zeros as follows:

```py
a = np.array[([[0,4,5,8,2],
 [2,3,4,1,3],
 [2,3,4,1,3],
 [2,3,4,1,3],
 [2,3,4,1,3]])

BC = np.array([0,3,4])

a[BC,:] = 0
a[:,BC] = 0
```

`[BC,:]` losely translates to "indicies of rows as in BC and all columns".

Comment: Ahhh yess that was fairly easy, thanks!!